# Properties of graph and associated bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $q(x,y)$ be bilinear form on vertexes of connected graph $V$: $q(v_i,v_j) = -1, i \neq j$ and $q(v_i,v_i) = 2$. I had proved that if $q > 0$ then $V$ is tree and if $q \geq 0$ then $V$ is tree or simple path. But how i can find all graphs such $q > 0$ or $q \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

A connected graph $\Gamma$ has positive definite bilinear form iff $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $A_n$, $D_n$ or $E_n$ for $n \leq 8$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram).

(I can sketch a proof if someone wants to see this.)